# VB.NET How to get text from an HTML table?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to access certain tables and values from a certain html page inside of a webbrowser control. Here's what i'm trying to access:

https://gyazo.com/c4312f860397d0f86ccce425d1fb3d48

In the end, I'm trying to access the value="100" inside of the input name="Server[players]". Is there any way to do this? I'm not using any external addons for visual studio or anything. I've already gotten this working:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim divs = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div")
    For Each div As HtmlElement In divs
        If div.GetAttribute("id") = ("statusdetail-ajax") Then
            Dim status As String = div.InnerText
            Label1.Text = status
        End If
    Next
```

Which just shows me the online/offline status. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the `GetAttribute()` method, like so:

```
Private Sub DisplayMetaDescription()
  If (WebBrowser1.Document IsNot Nothing) Then
    Dim Elems As HtmlElementCollection 
    Dim WebOC as WebBrowser = WebBrowser1

    Elems = WebOC.Document.GetElementsByTagName("META")

    For Each elem As HtmlElement In Elems
      Dim NameStr As String = elem.GetAttribute("name")

      If ((NameStr IsNot Nothing) And (NameStr.Length <> 0)) Then
        If NameStr.ToLower().Equals("description") Then
          Dim ContentStr As String = elem.GetAttribute("content")
          MessageBox.Show("Document: " & WebOC.Url.ToString() & vbCrLf & "Description: " & ContentStr)
        End If
      End If
    Next
  End If
End Sub
```

Taken from:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.getattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

**EDIT:**

Here's the same concept adapted to your code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  Dim inputs = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
  For Each input As HtmlElement In inputs
    If input.GetAttribute("id") = ("Server_players") Then
      Dim status As String = input.GetAttribute("value")
      Label1.Text = status
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

In other words, `InnerText` returns everything *between* elements, while `GetAttribute()` returns an attribute *inside* an element.

`<element attribute="Value">Inner Text</element>`

Comment: I pasted this in, and it works! But could you briefly describe what it's doing so I could modify it for further use? I took a look at that link and I'm not sure what exactly is going on here.

Comment: @DonaldCox: I adapted your code a bit—check the edits. Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Key_terminology.

Comment: @DonaldCox: If my answer solves your problem, would you mark it accordingly. If not, let me know and I'll try to help further.